# How do I assign vertex colors based upon a specified partition of the nodes?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm using `AdjacencyGraph` to plot a graph corresponding to an undirected, unweighted 5-node network. Each node is assigned a different color. Here's what I have so far:

```
A = {{0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 
1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}};
Labels = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
VertexNames = Table[i -> Labels[[i]], {i, 5}];
col = Range[5] /. {1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue, 4 -> Purple, 
5 -> Orange};
G = AdjacencyGraph[A, VertexLabels -> VertexNames, 
VertexStyle -> Thread[Range[5] -> col], VertexSize -> Medium, 
VertexLabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This does exactly as I would expect. However, now I want to assign colors based upon a partition of the vertices. For example, suppose I have
`{{1,3,4},{2,5}}` and I would like for the nodes in each of the two lists to be colored identically.

I'm not doing this for purposes of plotting a community partition as one would be using the `CommunityGraphPlot` command.

I do have IGraph/M installed if there's any easy way to accomplish this using it.

Answer (score 3):

HighlightGraph?:

```
HighlightGraph[G, {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5}}]

HighlightGraph[G, {Style[{1, 3, 4}, Blue], Style[{2, 5}, Orange]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`HighlightGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightGraph.html).

```
g = AdjacencyGraph[A, VertexSize -> Medium]

HighlightGraph[g, {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5}}]
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[g, {Style[{1, 3, 4}, Blue], Style[{2, 5}, Red]}]
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[g, {Labeled[{1, 3, 4}, "A", Center], 
  Labeled[{2, 5}, "B", Center]}, VertexLabelStyle -> White]
```

[image]

---

There are alternative ways to do this with IGraph/M, but in this case I recommend using the built-in `HighlightGraph` (unless you have a [good reason](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114725/12) not to).

```
IGVertexMap[
 ColorData[97],
 VertexStyle -> (IGPartitionsToMembership[VertexList[#], {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5}}] &),
 g
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to change the labels to emphasize that they are not the same as vertex nodes in what follows:

```
labels = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
vertexNames = MapIndexed[First[#2] -> # &, labels];
```

Color specification for nodes is given in this format:

```
{1 -> Red, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Red, 4 -> Blue, 5 -> Blue}
```

We can create this list in the following way:

```
groups = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}};
colors = Flatten@MapThread[Thread@*Rule, {groups, {Red, Blue}}];
```

where `Thread@*Rule` is the same as `Thread[# -> #2] &`.

We can now display the graph with this coloring:

```
AdjacencyGraph[
 A,
 VertexLabels -> vertexNames,
 VertexSize -> Medium,
 VertexLabelStyle -> Large,
 VertexStyle -> colors
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]